# Preventing generation of Realm JS files when running Jest in Javascript?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, realm, jestjs

I'm currently running `React-Native(0.51)` with `Jest(21.2.1)` and `RealmJS(2.1.1)`.

I've gotten them to play nicely where the RN app runs realm and my tests with jest work.

The issue is that after running Jest, I end up with some artifacts, specifically:

```
 * default.realm
 * default.realm.lock
 * default.realm.management/*
```

This causes issues when making an android release build where it freezes at `app::bundleReleaseJsAndAssets`. When I delete the files mentioned above, it works again.

To solve this I've just added the files to the `.gitignore` and excluding them in the gradle file like this:

```
project.ext.react = [
  inputExcludes: ["default.realm*"]
]
```

The question now is, how do I stop them from generating in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`Realm.deleteFile](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/2.1.0/api/Realm.html#.deleteFile) after each test.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I can't really use that because I don't actually have a configuration that I can pass to it. Calling it without the configuration doesn't do anything. That did lead me closer to what I wanted with `Realm.clearTestState()`. It removes all the previously generated artifacts, but unfortunately creates a new folder `realm-object-server` with more stuff inside. Is there anyway to remove all realm files during a test teardown?

Comment: You must have had a configuration when you opened the Realm?

Comment: `Realm.clearTestState()` is a hard method - it can be useful when testing. Otherwise, `Realm.deleteFile()` is the way to go. The `default.realm` name is used if you don't provide a `path` in the configuration.